# Problem converting a varchar to date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am importing dates in the format MM/DD/YYYY into a varchar field in MySQL importing from a pipe delimited CSV file.  The varchar field with the date after import is column_date_scratch.

After import, I am attempting to convert this column to a date field by populating another column using:
`UPDATE table SET column_date  = str_to_date(column_date_scratch, '%m/%d/%Y');`

The procedure works but I end up with a date that is a day earlier after the str to date conversion (i.e. if my varchar contains 11/04/2019, the date field ends up with 2019-11-03.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This actually just sounds like a timezone issue.  Perhaps there is a time zone difference between where your MySQL server is located and the source of the data.

Comment: Add time at the end of your field value and also in your format `str_to_date(column_date_scratch+' 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s');`

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I ended up setting the timezone in my.cnf and that worked, although I'm sure @hamid's solution would have worked as well.